# Приложение/уточнение или однородные члены после обобщающего слова

Tags: пунктуация, тире, приложение, двоеточие

**В описании вакансии есть два раздела [— / : ] «Обязанности» и «Требования».**

Тут «Обязанности» и «Требования» являются приложением к словосочетанию «два раздела», также можно это назвать и уточнением — и ставится тире?
Или это всё же обобщающее слово и однородные члены после него?

Пояснение:
"Обязанности" и "Требования" — это названия разделов, которые есть в описании вакансии. Это неполный состав разделов. Есть ещё "Условия". Следующее предложение за данным: "В них указаны..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Двоеточие ставят,** если даются **полные  названия разделов**, например: В описании вакансии есть два раздела:  «Квалификационные требования» и «Должностные обязанности». В этом случае однородные члены являются центром выказывания.

Если  темы разделов только названы, **то ставится тире:**  **В описании вакансии есть два раздела — «Обязанности» и «Требования».**  При постановке тире однородные члены имеют присоединительный (информирующий)  характер.

**Примечание**

Если это не единственные разделы, то они в любом случае посвящены определенной теме, и это должно быть ясно из предыдущего текста. На структуре данного предложения эта информация не должна отражаться.

Comment: Если темы разделов только названы, уместны ли кавычки?

Comment: Мне эти кавычки тоже не понравились, так как  разделы обычно не называются одним словом. Лучше казать так: В описании вакансии рассматриваются две основные темы - обязанности и требования.   Да и то не идеал: обязанности кого? требования к кому?

Comment: Коллеги, не нужно усложнять. Давайте поясню. "Обязанности" и "Требования" — это названия разделов, которые есть в описании вакансии. Это неполный состав разделов. Есть ещё "Условия". Следующее предложение за данным: "В них указаны...". Я так понял, что если здесь однородные члены имеют характер уточнения, то ставится тире, а когда они являются центром высказывания ("В описании вакансии есть разделы "Обязанности" и "Требования") — двоеточие.

Comment: Однако из ответов я понимаю, что, несмотря на то что здесь акцент делается на самих разделах "Обязанности" и "Требования", постановка двоеточия некорректна, ведь тогда создаётся впечатление, что разделов всего два — а это не соотносится с задуманным смыслов высказывания. Следовательно, ставим тире из-за характера приложения: какие-то два раздела и вот какие.

Comment: По-моему, вы преувеличиваете важность проблемы, так как в данном случае подходят оба варианта.  Если сложно выбрать, то используйте интонацию, при этом она должна вписаться в предыдущий текст. Хотите сделать подчеркнуто увеличенную  паузу, предупреждающую о последующем перечислении? Тогда ставьте двоеточие.  Если у вас нет такого желания, то используйте присоединительное тире (короткая пауза после полного понижения тона).

Answer (score 1):

*В описании вакансии есть два раздела [— / : ] «Обязанности» и «Требования».*

Из фразы не следует, что разделов в описании лишь два. Для конкретики ей не хватает точного названия документа — «Описание вакансии» и словесного утверждения: *только два*. Поэтому двоеточие неуместно, тире более соответствует свободной передаче сведений.

Для доведения информативности этой фразы до принятой в документообороте и названия разделов должны быть развёрнуты. Может быть выяснится, что двумя разделами не обойтись, и надо будет ввести нумерацию списка. Тогда можно прибегнуть к двоеточию.

Оставляя фразу, или её начало, в таком состоянии, можно обойтись скобками и убрать лишнее слово: *в описании вакансии — два раздела («Обязанности» и «Требования»).*

Comment: Нет, здесь имеется в виду то, что просто в описании есть два раздела. Они необязательно составляют весь список.

Comment: Приятно, когда — хоть и с опозданием в два дня — текст Автором уточняется. Жаль, что в комментарии, а не в самом тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

**В описании вакансии есть два раздела: «Обязанности» и «Требования».**

Читателю ясно, что именно два раздела, не больше.

**В описании вакансии есть два раздела — «Обязанности» и «Требования».**

Читателю остается лишь гадать, есть ли еще разделы помимо этих двух.

Измененный вариант:

**Описание вакансии разделено на два раздела: «Обязанности» и «Требования».**

(Тут есть тавтология, но она, по-моему, простительна в деловом стиле, если вносит ясность.)